# Jackson : default typing for main/container type only

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I would like to ask if there is any option to turn on default typing for main, "containter" class only?

I have a simple, testing class "Document" which is my container type for data. I want to turn on default typing for that class but not for classes which are inside "Document".

Also I want to do the same for any other classes (and not to annotate with @JsonTypeInfo manually)

```
{
    "@class": "com.example.demo.test.Document",
    "id": null,
    "testingLong": [
            "java.lang.Long",
            5
    ],
    "accountId": 10,
    "internal": {
        "@class": "com.example.demo.test.Internal",
        "id": "1",
    },
    "list": [
        "java.util.ArrayList",
        [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    ]
}
```